# Disabling a button element on page load in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, button, jquery-mobile

I have what is likely a simple problem, whereby I am trying to get a jquery mobile button to be disabled upon page initialization, with the following:

```
<body>
<section id="firstpage" data-role="page-content">
  <header data-role="header">
    <h1>Working with Buttons</h1>
  </header>
  <div data-role="content">
    <p>This is a &lt;button&gt; element:</p>
    <button id="btn1">button element</button>
  </div>
</section>
<script>
  $("#firstpage").live('pageinit', function (evt) {
    $("#btn1").button("disable");
  });
</script>
</body>
```

The page loads with all the jquery mobile formatting and behaviors as expected, but the button remains enabled. Any ideas? What very simple detail am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `disabled=true` attribute. jQuery Mobile will read that attribute and initialize the widget as disabled.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CDYgD/

Also, `data-role="page-content"`, `page-content` is not a valid jQuery Mobile `data-role` for a pseudo-page element, it should be just `page` unless you've made some type of customization. Docs for this: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.2/docs/api/data-attributes.html (look for `Page` header)

Comment: Greetings Jasper. Thank you for such a quick response. The "page-content" rather than "page" as the data-role was causing me the problem. Ughghghg! Also, your demo in jsfiddle, such a handy tool, I'll be using that from now on.